# Function definition paradox

Tags: function, julia

Consider the following definitions of function in Julia:

```
plustwo = function(x)
    x + 2
end

function addtwo(x)
    x + 2
end
```

To my surprise both definitions are valid, and behave the same way. Namely,

```
typeof(plustwo)
julia> Function

typeof(addtwo)
julia> Function

plustwo(3)
julia> 5

addtwo(3)
julia> 5
```

Any comments on this?

Does it mean that there are several dialects within Julia?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both of them are functions but, `addtwo` is a `generic` function which could have different methods, while `plustwo` is an `anonymous` function.

```
julia> addtwo.env
# 1 method for generic function "addtwo":
addtwo(x) at none:2

julia> plustwo.env
svec()
```

One could simply alter the code of an anonymous function, at runtime,

```
 julia> plustwo.code
AST(:($(Expr(:lambda,Any[:(x::Any)],Any[Any[Any[:x,:Any,0]],Any[],0,Any[]], :(
begin  # none, line 2:
        return x + 2
    end)))))

julia> addtwo.code
ERROR: UndefRefError: access to undefined reference
```

`generic` functions have better performance and `anonymous` functions are more suitable for `META` programming.

Comment: Also, the second form will implicitly make `addtwo` a `const`, which allows the compiler to optimise a lot more cases since the function to be called is known.

Comment: Here is the relevant documentation from the manual: http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/functions/#anonymous-functions

Comment: > *__generic__ functions have better performance and __anonymous__ functions are more suitable for META programming.* 

Note that this is going to change, for the better! https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/13412 :D